# JSF 1.2 - Unable to find component (...) We'll try to return a guessed client-id anyways

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

First of all, I'm working under JSF 1.2 / Richfaces 3.3 / Tomahawk 1.1.9 .

I have this piece of code inside one JSF page (simplified):

```html
<h:form id="mainForm">
(...)
<h:panelGroup id="grupSelMalaltia">
    <rich:panel header="Panel Name">
        <t:subform id="selMalaltiesForm">

            <rich:dataTable align="center" id="dataSelMalalties" value="#{TaulaMalalties.listMalalties}" var="cMal">

                (some <rich:column>)

                <rich:column>
                    <t:commandLink actionFor="selMalaltiesForm" action="select_malaltia">
                        <f:param name="has_selection" value="true">
                        <h:graphicImage url="/Icons/select.png" />
                    </t:commandLink>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>

        </t:subform>
    </rich:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
```

I'm getting this error:

`INFO: Unable to find component 'selMalaltiaForm' (calling findComponent on component 'mainForm:selMalaltiesForm:dataSelMalalties:0:j_id_jsp_2136723630_43'). We'll try to return a guessed client-id anyways - this will be a problem if you put the referenced component onto a different naming-contaier. If this is the case you can always use the full client-id.`

When the button is pressed, I just want to get this subform submitted (I have other JSF pages with similar code that run without problems). At this moment, because of this problem, I'm not getting this result.

How can I solve this malfunction? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a `<a4j:commandLink>` and set the `process` tag attribute with the ID's of the components you want/need to process.

Based in your proposed JSF code, it could be done like this

```html
<rich:panel header="Panel Name">
    <rich:dataTable align="center" id="dataUnselMalalties"
        value="#{TaulaMalalties.listMalalties}" var="cMal">
        <!-- richfaces columns with info -->
        <rich:column>
            <!-- processing the datatable only -->
            <a4j:commandLink action="#{TaulaMalalties.select_malaltia}"
                process="dataUnselMalalties" limitToList="true">
                <f:param name="has_selection" value="true">
                <h:graphicImage url="/Icons/select.png" />
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</rich:panel>
```

More info about this:

- [RichFaces 3.3: 5.7.4. Decide what to process](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#process)

Comment: In that case, i don't need to declare any subform, do I? I'll try your proposal.

Comment: @jmrodrigg no subform at all.